# Screenshot of a cell in ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I really need your help with how to solve my screenshot problem. First of all, when I tapped on one of the cells of the ForEach loop, the ScreenShotButton() will popup, and when I tapped the screenshot icon, I want to take a screenshot of that specific cell (not the entire screen, only the specific cell). The problem with my code is the screenshot doesn't work. I've been testing several ways, and I am out of options except posting my question here. Thanks in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

class ScreenShotViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var openMenu: Bool = false
    @Published var menuIndex: Int? = nil
    @Published var takePic: Bool = false
}

struct Home: View {
    
//@EnvironmentObject var tap: ScreenShotViewModel
@StateObject private var tap = ScreenShotViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1..<21) { index in
                ZStack {
                    PrintableCells(index: index)
                        .environmentObject(tap)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            tap.openMenu.toggle()
                            tap.menuIndex = index
                        }
                    
                    if tap.openMenu {
                        
                        Color.black.opacity(0.75)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tap.openMenu = false
                                tap.menuIndex = nil
                            }
                        
                        ScreenShotButton(index: index)
                            .environmentObject(tap)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
            .environmentObject(ScreenShotViewModel())
    }
}

struct PrintableCells: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: ScreenShotViewModel
    let index: Int
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(height: 200)
            .overlay(
                Text("ScreenShot: \(index)")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            )
            .background(
                ZStack {
                    if tap.menuIndex == index {
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Color.clear.onAppear() {
                                contentHeight = proxy.size.height
                            }.onChange(of: tap.takePic) { (newVal) in
                                if newVal {
                                    let image = self.takeScreenShot(origin: proxy.frame(in: .global).origin, size: proxy.size)

                                    print(image)

                                    tap.takePic = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        
    }
}

struct ScreenShotButton: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: ScreenShotViewModel
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        if tap.menuIndex == index {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Button {
                    tap.takePic.toggle()
                    tap.openMenu = false
                    tap.menuIndex = nil
                } label: {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.viewfinder")
                        Text("SnapShot Cell: \(index)")
                    }
                }

            }
            .padding(15)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.8))
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .shadow(color: .green, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func takeScreenShot(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return hosting.view.screenShot
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var screenShot: UIImage {
        let rect = self.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render (in: context)
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make the screenshot of a cell "work", I had to replace `EnvironmentObject` with
`ObservedObject` in `PrintableCells`. I also added a few bits of code to
show it is working. Here is the code that works for me:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class ScreenShotViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var openMenu: Bool = false
    @Published var menuIndex: Int? = nil
    @Published var takePic: Bool = false
    @Published var picture: [UIImage?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: 21)  // <--- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var tap = ScreenShotViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1..<21) { index in
                ZStack {
                    
                    // display the screenshot if any
                    if tap.picture[index] != nil {  // <--- here
                        Image(uiImage: tap.picture[index]!)
                            .colorMultiply(.green)  // <--- just for testing
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tap.openMenu.toggle()
                                tap.menuIndex = index
                            }
                    } else {
                        PrintableCells(tap: tap, index: index) // <--- here pass the tap model
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tap.openMenu.toggle()
                                tap.menuIndex = index
                            }
                    }
                    
                    if tap.openMenu && tap.menuIndex == index {  // <--- here
                        Color.black.opacity(0.75)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tap.openMenu = false
                                tap.menuIndex = nil
                            }
                        ScreenShotButton(index: index) // <--- here
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(tap)  // <--- here
    }
}

struct PrintableCells: View {
    @ObservedObject var tap: ScreenShotViewModel    // <--- here as ObservedObject
    let index: Int
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(height: 200)
            .overlay(Text("ScreenShot: \(index)").font(.title3).fontWeight(.bold))
            .background(
                ZStack {
                    if tap.menuIndex == index {
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Color.clear
                                .onAppear() {
                                    contentHeight = proxy.size.height
                                }
                                .onChange(of: tap.takePic) { newVal in
                                    if newVal {
                                        let img = self.takeScreenShot(origin: proxy.frame(in: .global).origin, size: proxy.size)
                                        tap.picture.remove(at: index)
                                        tap.picture.insert(img, at: index)
                                        tap.takePic = false
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}

struct ScreenShotButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: ScreenShotViewModel
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        if tap.menuIndex == index {
            ZStack {
                Button {
                    tap.takePic.toggle()
                    tap.openMenu = false
                    // tap.menuIndex = nil   // <--- here
                } label: {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.viewfinder")
                        Text("SnapShot Cell: \(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(15)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.8))
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .shadow(color: .green, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func takeScreenShot(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return hosting.view.screenShot
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var screenShot: UIImage {
        let rect = self.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render (in: context)
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog. This is awesome, and you are amazing. I believe that every new developer always can learn something from your code.

Comment: Also thank you for the commands they are very helpful for me because I need to know where I am doing wrong.